# How do I use PivotTables to sum a variable, but where rows are repeated for subclasses?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

[image]

Here, I have some vehicle data, attached with some corresponding information about the where the owners of these types of vehicles live, and their average house price.

Clearly the house price/location doesn't directly affect the vehicle value, but is useful for statistical inference.

What I want to do is to create a pivot table - however when considering the average vehicle value, the pivottable sums up each type of Vehicle/Model class multiple times as shown below:

[image]

And so, while the average House Price column in the pivottable is correct, the vehicle value is incorrectly counted multiple times (with respect to the Vehicle Make).

Comment: In pivot field you have stated that the average value of a car should be summed up, what result did you expect?

Comment: I'm not sure that I've explained it very well. I want the Vehicle Value for Mercedes to be the sum of average values of the Mercedes without repeating the values based on the number of different locations, but rather just based on the unique combinations of Vehicle/Model.

Comment: E.g. Vehicle Value for Mercedes = $6,000+$4,000 = $10,000

Comment: E.g. Vehicle Value for Mercedes, A Class = $6,000 (not $12,000)

Comment: Is there such a thing like a "Distinct Sum"? As I'm aware there is a Distinct Count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no DistinctSum function in the pivot table. The only thing that comes to mind is to add an additional column in the base table where the required values can be calculated. For example, in the column 'Distinct value' you can insert the following formula:

```
=D2/SUMPRODUCT((A2=$A$2:$A$13)*(B2=$B$2:$B$13))
```

it calculates the `Value / Count of values` for each car and model and then in the pivot table sum this column.

[image]